# Data abort exception when writing to peripheral register

Tags: cortex-a

My program raises an data abort exception when i write any value to an adress of a peripheral register (Multi I/O SPI Interface). I am using an Renesas RZ/A1L processor with an cortex A9 core.

Interestingly in another project the same sourcecode and the same store instruction does not result in such an exception.

There must be something before the execution of the store instruction that forbids writing to this address or results in a conflicting access to this address.

Interestingly doing single steps over the critical instructions in the disassembly, sometimes resulting in raising no exception and the next instrucitons can be executed. But even then writing or reading (load/store) to and from the next register in the same memory region can result in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The exception was raised by the MMU. The memory section that contained the addresses for the multi I/O SPI interface registers were not configured in the MMU.

Why single stepping in the disassembly did not trigger a MMU data abourt exception is still not resolved.